# Winter 20 : Getting Promise rejection, intermittently, when we close tab

Tags: lightning, console

On tabClose we have started reciveing an error message :

```
[PromiseRejection: Error: getTabInfo() - Failed to get tabInfo for tabId `ctab7`]
{anonymous}()@https://*****.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/PBO944yw5MGHc- 
5iZ4R1Jw/aura_prod.js:928:238 e.$$lwcEventWrapper$$()@https://*****.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/PBO944 
yw5MGHc-5iZ4R1Jw/aura_prod.js:1:4401
```

The triggering point for this is where we have used window.postMessage in our lightning sales console. Has anyone started experiencing this issue?

Patch applied : `CS53 Winter '20 Patch 5.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because, when the tab was closed, focused event for active tab was getting triggered, as the focus moves on the active tab, but the current tab is yet to be closed. And on focus there was a method written which gets the `enclosingTabId`, which in this case is the tab id of the tab which is getting closed.

And trying to fire a post message in closed tab id gives promise rejection. I gave a `setTimeout` of `400 milliseconds` and now its working fine.

Giving a setTimeout gives time for aura to close the tab and when the focused event is getting triggered, it takes the enclosing tab id of the active tab.